# How to call automatically method in object that needs access to unsaved associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, associations

I have a class called Treatment with these associations:

```
class Treatment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :threat_treatments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :threats, :through => :threat_treatments
  has_many :subcategory_treatments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :subcategories, :through => :subcategory_treatments      
  has_many :treatments_risks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :risks, :through => :treatments_risks
  has_many :risks_from_threats, :through => :threats, :source => :risks
  has_many :risks_from_subcategories, :through => :subcategories, :source => :risks

  def associate_with_existing_risks
    self.risks = self.risks_from_threats & self.risks_from_subcategories
  end      
end
```

I need to execute the method associate_with_existing_risks() automatically when a treatment is created. If I use before_save callback, the two associations are still unsaved and unaccessible. If I use after_save, cause I need to save again the treatment, I will create an infinite loop.

I cannot use inverse_of because the associations are through associations.

How and when can I execute the method associate_with_existing_risks to update the risks association when a treatment is created?

Comment: Could this be solved using the `after_initialize` callback?

Comment: Yes, I have checked that in 3.2.16 after_initialize has access to new associations. Thanks.